# Proxy & Memento Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy-pattern, memento

Proxy - what code (and where) translates ProxyService into RealService calls? Why/when use this?
Layers - how to implement?
Memento - why not just persist state to a cache or file?

My understanding of the **Proxy** pattern is that you have some kind of `Service` interface that has `ProxyService` and `RealService` concretions. For some reason, you can't access the `RealService`, so you code against a `ProxyService` instance and then let the framework link the proxy to the real instance of your service. Only two problems:

- I can't think of a single example when I would have access to `Service` and `ProxyService`, but not `RealService` - can someone provide examples as to when this could happen?

How is this different from the **Memento** pattern? My understanding of Memento's definition is that it is used for saving an object state, which is what a Proxy is really doing, yes? If not please explain how Memento is different than Proxy! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'll caveat my answer by saying that I don't believe there are any hard and fast rules about patterns - you take what you need from them and nothing more.  The way that I use certain patterns is undoubtedly different from how another developer might choose to use them.  That said, here's my take on your question.

**Proxy Pattern Explained**

The way I know the `Proxy` design pattern, you use it to do two things:

1. Restrict access to otherwise public methods of a particular object instance
2. Prevent otherwise-expensive, and unnecessary instantiation costs, by instantiating the concrete object on the first call to the proxy, then passing all further calls on the proxy through to the concrete instance your proxy created.

Maybe `RealService` has a method `doSomethingReallyDangerous()` that you want to hide.  Or even more innocuous, maybe `RealService` has several hundred methods that you don't need to see every time you type the `.` after a `RealService` instance's variable name.  You'd use a proxy for any of this.

For further reading, this article has a lot of good information:

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy

**Differences with Memento Pattern**

The `Memento` pattern allows you to roll back an object to its original state, or some previous state, by storing intermediate states alongside the concrete object.  Sort of like an "undo" for programming.  You'd probably use a `Proxy` pattern to implement `Memento`, but `Proxy` doesn't guarantee saving of object state or rollback - it just lets you refer to the same object for method calls if instantiating that object over again is prohibitively expensive.

So hopefully that helps - I like to think of `Memento` as a more full-featured version of `Proxy`, but not all `Proxy` implementations are `Mementos`.

Answer (score 2):

Proxy is when someone is expecting a certain object, and you lie to him, and you say: Yes, here you have your object, but you are actually giving him something else...
Common uses for proxy:
To implement Lazy initialization: You are asked for an object representing the contents of a big file, or something which is very expensive to acquire, and you know that it's not needed at this right moment, or it might in fact never be used really. So you pass a proxy, that will only acquire the resource when it's 100% completely necessary (You can also start acquiring the resource anachronistically, and make the process using the proxy only start waiting when it really needs it). This is pretty common in ORMs. Also [futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) implement something like this
To intercept calls:
You can pass a proxy which actually knows the real object, and intercept the calls that it gets, and do something interesting like logging them, changing some of them, etc...
There are also a lot of advanced and complex usages of the proxy, given that you often have the ability to determine the behavior at runtime. sorry for going out of Java, but in C#, [Castle Proxy](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=DynamicProxy&NS=Tools&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)  is used to implement mock objects for testing. You can also implement with a proxy things like [chaining in underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining). And you can simulate a lot of "dynamic languages" features in static languages using proxies. You can also evaluate a piece of code with a proxy that actually logs every call that is made, and returns new proxies every time, to reconstruct the "original source code" by just executing it.

Memento pattern: is another thing completely. You use it when you want to work with an object, save it current state, counting doing thins with that object, and after a while you might want to choose to rollback to the previous state. You can use it to implement transactional behavior in your objects, when undoing the things by code is difficult. You can implement undo & redo functionality with this. (Instead of saving the change-delta, you save the full state). You can use it in simulations to start every time from the same point (You could say that a Source Version Server uses memento every once in a while [they generally use a combination of memento + delta changes]). A snapshot of a virtual machine or an hibernate of a computer is also a use of the memento pattern. And saving the state of something, so you can reproduce the exact same situation is also memento.